# Unable to record Excel sheet in Loadrunner

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner, sap-gui

I am trying to do a Performance test with Loadrunner on Excel based application which is redirect from SAP GUI.

Loadrunner is able to record all the activity perform in SAP application but it's not recording anything for Excel.

My main target is to record the Excel, for testing the performance of the application.

I also try with QTP and succeed but as I want to conduct performance test, so the script is no use for me.

Any suggestions what protocol to use or any other scripting language for performance test on Excel based application with SAP GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And just what protocol is the excel spreadsheet using to communicate to what type of server?   Only when you answer that can you then answer how to reproduce the server communication behavior of your excel application.

On the other hand, if you are simply downloading a spreadsheet, modifying it locally and then uploading the changes without any server communication then you had better dust off your programming skills, download the current excel file format and prepare to make the modifications to the file in code (or have another static one to upload)

Comment: It's a SAP GUI application, so I am using sap GUI protocol for recording the script, problem is it's not recording for excel application which is with BEX analyzer and it communicate with SAP BEX Analyzer. So, can you please help me on this topic.

Comment: Get a Protocol Analyzer, such as Sniffer, Wireshark, etc.., capture the messages sent back and forth to excel and then build extensions to your SAPGUI script to communicate with that host to represent the flows from Excel.